# How to protect yourself when refactoring non-regression tests?

Tags: testing, refactoring

Are there specific techniques to consider when refactoring the non-regression tests?  The code is usually pretty simple, but it's obviously not included into the safety net of a test suite...

When building a non-regression test, I first ensure that it really exhibits the issue that I want to correct, of course.  But if I come back later to this test because I want to refactor it (e.g. I just added another very similar test), I usually can't put the code-under-test back in a state where it was exhibiting the first issue.  So I can't be sure that the test, once refactored, is still exercising the same paths in the code.

Are there specific techniques to deal with this issue, except being extra careful?

Comment: You need tests for your tests. Being serious now, you need to learn to trust yourself and your code at some point. Unit tests should never be considered perfect  - especially as your test suite grows so does the likelyhood that you have got something wrong somewhere, even when you are considered to be a guru your code will never be faultless. IOW - you just need to learn to live with the paranoia that you have about your tests :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a big problem.  The tests test the code, and the code tests the tests.  Although it's possible to make a clumsy mistake that causes the test to start passing under all circumstances, it's not likely.  You'll be running the tests again and again, so the tests and the code they test gets a lot of exercise, and when things change for the worse, tests generally start failing.

Of course, be careful; of course, run the tests immediately before and after refactoring.  If you're uncomfortable about your refactoring, do it in a way that allows you to see the test working (passing *and* failing).  Find a reliable way to fail each test before the refactoring, and write it down.  Get to green - all tests passing - then refactor the test.  Run the tests; still green?  Good.  (If not, of course, get green, perhaps by starting over).  Perform the changes that made the original unrefactored tests fail.  Red?  Same failure as before?  Then reinstate the working code, and check for green again.  Check it in and move onto your next task.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include not only positive cases in your automated test, but also negative cases (and a proper handler for them).

Also, you can try to run your refactored automated test with breakpoints and supervise through the debugger that it keeps on exercising all the paths you intended it to exercise.